# LineBreak in a Run

Tags: wpf, line-breaks

How to have a LineBreak in a run?
In mean IN
The content coming in dynamically has line breaks
I know a LineBreak between runs works
`<LineBreak/>` in a run throws a syntax error
Below are the options I have tried - none of them work

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>Run1</Run>
    <LineBreak/>  
    <Run>Run2a&#10;Run2b\r\nRun2c/r/nRun2d&#xA;Run2e&lt;LineBreak/&gt;Run2gRun2e</Run>          
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: how about a converter?

Comment: @bto.rdz I am actually using a converter.  It still breaks IN a Run (for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try &#x0a; , using inside of Text attribute:

```
<Run Text="Text&#x0a;Next Line" />
```

Comment: That does answer the stated question.  My problem now is that I get some line breaks that are not in a run and this does not work outside a run.  Let me delay the check for a couple days as other ideas may get posted.

Comment: @Frisbee It can work inside many Text or Content attributes, of TextBlock, for example. Actually, it's interesting to know, where it doesn't work.

Comment: I ended up doing it with TextBlock (in a TextBlock ) but this is a proper answer to the stated question.